# Arrays by User input and binary search returning "not found" when # does exist

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

Currently learning C# any help appreciated.

```
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] clerkNumbers = {11111, 33333, 55555, 00000, 44444,
        88888, 90000, 22222, 66666, 77777};
        string[] clerkNames = {"JOHN GOOD", "MARY SELLER", "TOM CAP", "LISA MARKS",
        "JANE PHELPS", "MIKE SMITH", "KAREN SPEEL", "LORI THOMAS", "GEORGE STREET", "PAT JONES"};
        double[] clerkPercent = { 20, 15, 18, 25, 14, 12, 17, 16, 20, 21 };

        string[] months = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
        int[] monthNumbers = { 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12 };
        double[] monthPercentage = { .10, .12, .15, .20, .21, .10, .10, .12, .14, .20, .34, .20 };

        //double[] USERclerkNumbers = { 44444, 66666, 22222, 20000, 33333, 55555, 88888 };
        //double[] USERmonthlySales = { 1201.00, 2401.05, 3000.00, 2000.00, 5071.01, 1500.50, 0980.00 };
        //int[] USERmonthNumber = { 03, 11, 01, 02, 09, 06, 04 };

        //for (int i = 0; i < clerkNumbers.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    for (int x = 0; x < clerkNames.Length; x++)
        //    {
        //        for (int a = 0; a < clerkPercent.Length; a++)
        //        {
        //            for (int b = 0; b < USERclerkNumbers.Length; b++)
        //            {
        //                if (USERclerkNumbers[b] == clerkNumbers[i])
        //                {
        //                    double[] commission = new double [10];
        //                    for (int v = 0; v < commission.Length; v++)
        //                    {
        //                        commission[v] = USERmonthlySales[b] * monthPercentage[b];
        //                        WriteLine("SALES REPORT", 20);
        //                        WriteLine("Clerk Number: {0}", 5, "Name: {1}", 10, "Month: {2}", 15, "Commission: {3}", 20,
        //                            clerkNumbers[b], clerkNames[x], USERmonthNumber[b], commission[b]);
        //                    }              
        //                }
        //            }
        //        }
        //    }
        //}

        double[] USERclerkNumbers = new double[10];
        double[] USERmonthlySales = new double[10];
        int[] USERmonthNumber = new int[10];
        double[] commission = new double[10];
        double[] EXIT = {99999};
        for (int i = 0; i < USERclerkNumbers.Length;)
        {
            Write("Please Enter Clerk #: ");                
            USERclerkNumbers[i] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
            foreach (double clerkNumber in clerkNumbers)
            {
                if (USERclerkNumbers[i] == clerkNumber)
                {
                    for (int a = 0; a < USERmonthlySales.Length; a++)
                    {
                        Write("Please Enter Monthly Sales For {0}: ", USERclerkNumbers[a]);
                        USERmonthlySales[a] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
                        for (int b = 0; b < USERmonthNumber.Length; b++)
                        {
                            Write("Please Enter Month For Clerk: {0} With Sales Of: {1} : ", USERclerkNumbers[a], USERmonthlySales[a]);
                            USERmonthNumber[b] = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
                            i++;

                        }

                    }

                }
                else if (USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumber)
                {
                   WriteLine("Clerk Number Not Found!");
                    //i--;
                }                    
            }
        }
        for (int v = 0; v < commission.Length; v++)
        {
            commission[v] = USERmonthlySales[v] * monthPercentage[v];
            WriteLine("SALES REPORT", 20);
            WriteLine("Clerk Number: {0}", 5, "Name: {1}", 10, "Month: {2}", 15, "Commission: {3}", 20,
                clerkNumbers[v], clerkNames[v], USERmonthNumber[v], commission[v]);                
        }
        ReadLine();

    }
}
```

OLDER:
   {

```
        Write("How Many Clerks Do You Need To Enter? ");
        int LIMIT = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

        double[] USERclerkNumbers = new double[LIMIT];
        double[] USERmonthlySales = new double[LIMIT];
        int[] USERmonthNumber = new int[LIMIT];
        double[] commission = new double[LIMIT];
        double EXIT = 99999;

        for (int i = 0; i < USERclerkNumbers.Length;)
        {
            Write("Please Enter Clerk #: ");
            if (USERclerkNumbers[i] != EXIT)
            {
                USERclerkNumbers[i] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
                i++;
            }
            if (USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumbers[0] && USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumbers[1] && USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumbers[2] &&
                USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumbers[3] && USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumbers[4] && USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumbers[5] &&
                USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumbers[6] && USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumbers[7] && USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumbers[8] &&
                USERclerkNumbers[i] != clerkNumbers[9])               
            {
                WriteLine("ERROR: Clerk Number Not Found");
            }
        }            
        for (int a = 0; a < USERclerkNumbers.Length; a++)
        {
            Write("Please Enter Monthly Sales For {0}: ", USERclerkNumbers[a]);
            USERmonthlySales[a] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
        }
        for (int b = 0; b < USERclerkNumbers.Length; b++)
        {
            Write("Please Enter Month For Clerk: {0} With Sales Of: {1} : ", USERclerkNumbers[b], USERmonthlySales[b]);
            USERmonthNumber[b] = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
        }
        for (int v = 0; v < commission.Length; v++)
        {
            commission[v] = USERmonthlySales[v] * monthPercentage[v];
            WriteLine("SALES REPORT", 25);
            WriteLine("Clerk Number: {0}", 5, "Name: {1}", 10, "Month: {2}", 15, "Commission: {3}", 20,
                clerkNumbers[v], clerkNames[v], USERmonthNumber[v], commission[v]);
        }
        ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

CURRENTLY:

```
        Array.Sort(clerkNames.ToArray(), clerkPercent);
        Array.Sort(clerkNames.ToArray(), clerkNumbers);
        Array.Sort(clerkNames);

        Write("How Many Clerks Do You Need To Enter? ");
        int LIMIT = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
        double[] USERclerkNumbers = new double[LIMIT];
        int x;
        for (int i = 0; i < USERclerkNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Write("Please Enter {0} Clerk Number: ", i);
            USERclerkNumbers[i] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
            x = Array.BinarySearch(clerkNumbers, USERclerkNumbers[i]);
            if (x < 0)
            {
                WriteLine("Clerk Number {0} Not Found.", USERclerkNumbers[i]);
                //i--;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }

        double[] USERmonthlySales = new double[USERclerkNumbers.Length];
        int[] USERmonthNumber = new int[USERclerkNumbers.Length];
        double[] commission = new double[USERclerkNumbers.Length];

        for (int a = 0; a < USERclerkNumbers.Length; a++)
        {
            Write("Please Enter Monthly Sales For {0}: ", USERclerkNumbers[a]);
            USERmonthlySales[a] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
        }
        for (int b = 0; b < USERclerkNumbers.Length; b++)
        {
            Write("Please Enter Month For Clerk: {0} With Sales Of: {1} : ", USERclerkNumbers[b], USERmonthlySales[b]);
            USERmonthNumber[b] = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
        }
        for (int v = 0; v < commission.Length; v++)
        {
            commission[v] = USERmonthlySales[v] * monthPercentage[v];

        }
        WriteLine("SALES REPORT", 0,25);
        WriteLine("------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < clerkNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            WriteLine("Clerk Number: {0} ------ Name: {1} ------- Month: {2} ------ Commission: {3} ------",
            clerkNumbers[i], clerkNames[i], USERmonthNumber[i], commission[i]);
        }
        WriteLine("99999", 5);
        ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

The commented out section is a previous attempt on how to accomplish this.
Last transaction will be followed by an entry of "99999" in the clerk number field.

Ideally I would like it to ask for user input for each person then exit to do calculations with that data. I could put each one separate but then I'll be entering just the "Clerk #s" first then sales amounts then month.

Output:                 SALES REPORT

Clerk Number         Name              Month            Commission

xxxxxxxxx           xxxxxxxxxxxx        xx           $999.99

Lost in the loops however that where my question is!
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Or should it ask for all data and exit on 99999 entry.

EDIT TWO: Separated loops for input confused on how to stop the array at either exit or invalid in array.
DATA is all listed at top in arrays random fake data.

EDIT THREE: ADDED MY CURRENT TRY.

Comment: You can take whatever approach you like based on what you're trying to achieve; there's no technical restriction there.  In terms of getting lost in loops, try making them more readable; e.g. replace `int i` with `int clerkNumberIndex`, so you know what that variable's for.  Additionally, you don't need to hold all the values in separate arrays; you can create a class which holds all those properties, and can then have an array (or some other collection/list structure) of that type, holding one entry per clerk's details, with all relevant details in that entry.

Comment: ps. it looks like you don't have one specific question, but rather need lots of help. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place for getting such feedback.

Comment: @JohnLBevan No, it looks like the user doesn't know how to fix his problem. Code with problems which cause the code not to work as expected are hugely off-topic at Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a code review than an answer to a specific question, but hopefully useful.

#### Make use of classes...

...to hold multiple properties relating to a single entity, rather than having an array per property and relying on a common index (e.g. item #5 in each list) relating to the same entity:

```
public class Clerk
{
    public double Number {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //I've used a dictionary type below; the first int for the month number, the second for the clerk's monthly sales
    public IDictionary<int, int> SalesFigures {get;set;} 
    public Clerk (double number, string name) 
    {
        this.Number = number;
        this.Name = name;
        this.SalesFigures = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }
}
```

#### Break up code into nicely named chunks

Try to break up code into descriptive functions.  i.e. instead of:

```
//...
Write("Please Enter Clerk #: ");                
USERclerkNumbers[i] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
//...
```

You could have:

```
double clerkNumber = myInput.GetClerkNumber();
```

Where `myInput` is an object of type `MyInputClass` (better names are available):

```
public class MyInputClass
{
    private string GetUserInput(string message)
    {
        Write(message);                
        return ReadLine();          
    }
    public double GetClerkNumber()
    {                
        return Convert.ToDouble(GetUserInput("Please Enter Clerk #: "));        
    }
    //put your other UI bits here; e.g. functions to get monthly sales, month number, etc
}
```

This not only keeps all your UI pieces in one place (i.e. so later you could swap your UI with some other form of input; ideally by using a common `interface`, though that's something you'll learn about later).

Similarly you can do the same with the code calling the input functions:

```
const double EXIT_CODE = 99999;
public IEnumerable<Clerk> GetClerkData()
{
    MyInputClass myInput = new MyInputClass();
    bool collectMoreData = true;
    while (collectMoreData) 
    {
        double clerkNumber = myInput.GetClerkNumber();
        if (clerkNumber.Equals(EXIT_CODE))
        {
            collectMoreData = false; //we could use a `break;` statement here instead of using the collectMoreData flag; personally I think the flag's simpler to understand for a beginner / less prone to trip you up
        }
        else
        {
            string clerkName = myInput.GetClerkName();
            var newClerk = new Clerk(clerkNumber, clerkName);
            for (int monthNumber = 1; monthNumber <=12; monthNumber++)
            {
                int monthlySales = myInput.GetClerkSales(clerkName, monthNumber);
                newClerk.SalesFigures.Add(monthNumber, monthlySales);
            }
            yield return newClerk;
        }
    }
}
```

I'll leave this there to avoid rewriting the full solution for you; but hopefully this puts you on the right tracks to progress with this for yourself?

Comment: Thank You that makes a bit more sense for me. Unable to use Classes although i agree that would be easier same with .list

Comment: Also just added my current standing on program above.